# Plotting predicted common OR and 95% CI from an ordinal logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization, ordinal-data

I fitted an ordinal logistic regression model with a dependent variable of four ordered responses with one continuous predictor variable and 6 confounders, using the *polr* package in R.

It looks like this;

`m <- polr (FIST ~ cont_predictor + x1 + x2 + x3 ..., data=data, Hess=TRUE)`

After I get the common OR and 95% CI from the model, I wanted to draw a plot showing **predicted cOR** over the range of *cont_predictor* (13 - 167).

I've applied *predict* to the model, like this;

`pred <- predict(m, newdata=data, type="probs", interval="confidence", se.fit=TRUE)`

and *cbind* the *cont_predictor* here.
`test <- cbind (pred, x=data$cont_predictor)`

What data I have in the *test* matrix is like this;

```
           1         2         3         4  x
1  0.3340795 0.2747667 0.2301364 0.1610175 62
2  0.2728124 0.2650788 0.2578796 0.2042293 36
3  0.2958057 0.2700358 0.2476891 0.1864694 33
4  0.3508921 0.2755857 0.2223387 0.1511836 45
5  0.2440494 0.2563633 0.2698620 0.2297253 60
6  0.2223108 0.2477265 0.2780087 0.2519541 76
7  0.2039479 0.2389167 0.2839792 0.2731561 40
8  0.2454748 0.2568656 0.2692959 0.2283637 70
9  0.2173119 0.2454709 0.2797295 0.2574877 40
10 0.3683285 0.2756930 0.2142581 0.1417204 36
```

Now, I don't know how to calculated the **common OR** from this matrix.
Can anyone help me to draw a plot of common OR and 95% CI?

Thank you.